# How can I count all the records in the both tables in a 1:n relationship in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm guessing this a fairly easy question, but I've run into this problem a number of times and I can't find a solution either through searching (maybe I don't know what to search for) or trial and error.

I have the following table structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `table_b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `table_b_id` (`table_b_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_a` VALUES(1, 1, 'test 1');
INSERT INTO `table_a` VALUES(2, 1, 'test 2');
INSERT INTO `table_a` VALUES(3, 0, 'test 3');

CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_b` VALUES(1, 'value 1');
INSERT INTO `table_b` VALUES(2, 'value 2');
```

As you can see, id 2 in `table_b` is not used in `table_a` and id 3 in `table_a` has a value of 0 for `table_b_id`. What I want to do is retrieve a count of the number of times each value in b is used in `table_a`, including 2 from `table_b` and count of all the values not in `table_b`.

I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(a.id) AS number
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON (b.id = a.table_b_id)
GROUP BY a.table_b_id
```

But it obviously only returns the following:

```
name       number
-----------------
null       1
value 1    2
```

How can I get the following, with only SQL:

```
name       number
-----------------
null       1
value 1    2
value 2    0
```

I am using MySQL. I'm guessing the answer is simple.

**Edit:** Is there no other way other than a union'd query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.name, SUM(case when a.id is null then 0 else 1 end) AS number
FROM table_a AS a
RIGHT JOIN table_b AS b ON (b.id = a.table_b_id)
GROUP BY b.id
```

If you want to get the null row, that is special. I believe you'll have to UNION it.

```
SELECT b.name, SUM(case when a.id is null then 0 else 1 end) AS number 
FROM table_a AS a
RIGHT JOIN table_b AS b ON (b.id = a.table_b_id)
GROUP BY b.id
UNION
select null, count(1) from table_a where table_b_id not in ( select id from table_b )
```

Comment: This excludes the one that isn't in table_b (a.id = 3).

Comment: Eh, You could just union it with count of nulls from a left join, but I won't steal Jamie's work.  I was gonna answer the question when you posted it the first time, but then it got deleted, and I was like, eh forget it!

Comment: Sorry man, slightly different question. I forgot to mention that I need all of the records in both tables, not just table b. I didn't want to change it to basically tell everyone they wre wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is called `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

As for now, `MySQL` lacks this feature, that means you'll need to emulate is with a `UNION` (which is not too bad as you still do it in a single query).

```
SELECT  name, SUM(IF(a.id IS NULL, 0, 1))
FROM    table_b b
LEFT JOIN
        table_a a
ON      a.table_b_id = b.id
GROUP BY
        b.id
UNION ALL
SELECT  name, COUNT(*)
FROM    table_a a
LEFT JOIN
        table_b b
ON      b.id = a.table_b_id
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
GROUP BY
        b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This nested query would work with mysql 5

```
SELECT b.name, (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM table_a AS a WHERE a.table_b_id = b.id) AS amount FROM table_b AS b
```

Comment: This excludes the one that isn't in table_b (a.id = 3).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lengthy discussion of various ways to solve this problem on [this post by Xaprb](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/).  He shows how to avoid using a `UNION`, although the alternative mechanism requires an extra "mutex" table and he suggests it's slower than using a `UNION`.